# How can I force IE9/10 to use IE8 for BOTH document mode and browser mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible, ie8-browser-mode

I would like IE9 and IE10 to use IE8 for both Document Mode *and* Browser Mode. I'm using the following, and Document Mode gets set to "IE8 standards," but Browser Mode is still set to IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>IE Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
</head>
<body>

<p>some text here afskdjflewnqrkweqn lrwenhrwejfaskdjfhsdsd</p>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to force Browser Mode to be IE8? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controlling the browser mode isn't possible from the site itself.

The Browser Mode setting is controlled by the Compatibility View list (clientside) only. The Document Mode setting is controlled by the browser mode and/or the `X-UA-Compatible` header.